# View moves up when status bar hidden

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an app where i have set the status bar to be hidden, in the plist.

At first all looks fine, but then in one place in my app i use presentModalViewController to show another view. (this view is to show the twitter login screen)

When i get out of the view (twitter login screen) and i get back in my app all my views move up.

After reading a lot i know its because all the views think that the status bar is hidden and we should move up 20 pixels, but i have already accounted for the status bar being hidden and i dont want the views to move up.

Is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: what's the code you use to switch views? Usually, should be ok calling `subview.frame = superview.bounds` before calling `addSubView:`